# How to make 3 buttons be clicked in a certain order go to certain frame? Flash AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, button, sequence

I am struggling making 3 buttons be able to go to a frame when the buttons are clicked in a certain order. For example the buttons are labeled
button 1
button 2
button 3

and the order that they are needed to be clicked in is button 3, button 1, button 2 for them to go to the next frame, How can I achieve this?

This is what I have so far.

```
 var clicked = MouseEvent.CLICK 
 var buttons = new Array(YellowButton, BlueButton, RedButton); 
 for (var a=0; a<buttons.lenght; a++) 
 { 
   buttons[a].buttonMode=true 
   buttons[a].addEventListener(clicked,RedYellowBlue); 
 } 

 function RedYellowBlue(event:MouseEvent):void { gotoAndStop(20); }
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! To get a positive response here, please show what you have tried.

Comment: I have edited your code into the post. You can do this yourself, too. Hopefully this will help you go get some useful answers. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I recommend is to create a string object that will be assembled by clicking the buttons, and then compared to a particular sequence that you set. The beauty of this is that you can make it work for sequences of any length.

The biggest thing here is, you don't want the same event listener on all three buttons. You want their actions to be unique, otherwise, clicking one is the same as clicking all the others (which is your current code's problem.)

```
var checkString:String = "";

//Create event listeners and their functions.
YellowButton.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, yellowClick);
RedButton.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, redClick);
BlueButton.addEventListener(Mouse.CLICK, blueClick);

function yellowClick(evt:Event):void
{
   //In each event listener function, add a letter or 
   //string to the checkString variable.
   checkString += "y";

   //Then, see if the string matches or not.
   check();
}

function redClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "r";
   check();
}

function blueClick(evt:Event):void
{
   checkString += "b";
   check();
}

//If the proper sequence is red, yellow, blue, the string would read "ryb".
function check():void
{
   if(checkString == "ryb")
   {
      //Clear the checkString for convenience before going on.
      clearString();
      //CODE TO GO TO NEW FRAME
      gotoAndStop(20);
   }
   else
   {
      //Make sure the string is at least 3 characters long.
      if(checkString.length >= 3)
      {
         clearString();
         gotoAndStop(foo);
      }
   }
}

function clearString():void
{
   //You will want to have a function for clearing the string.
   //This is especially useful if you have a button for "start over."
   checkString = "";
}
```

That should be sufficient to get you started. If you need additional help, feel free to comment on my answer.

Comment: Thanks so much Jason that is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks Again Ollie

Comment: Good suggestion! However, setting the string should be: `checkString += "r";` (not `=+`)

Comment: If this answer is/was helpful don't forget to accept it (and possibly upvote).

Comment: Hi Jason I have one question which I hope you could help me with. How can I code it so that any incorrect order of the buttons clicked will go to a certain frame?Thanks again for all your help

Comment: I've edited the answer so you can see that. :D (Look at the check() function) [And thanks for editing, Scrimothy]

Answer (score 0):

To consolidate @JasonMc92's answer, you could use the name of the target as the `checkString` letter so you only need to call one function for all buttons.

```
yellowButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redYellowBlue);
redButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redYellowBlue);
blueButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, redYellowBlue);

function redYellowBlue(e:MouseEvent){
  checkString += e.currentTarget.name.substr(0,1);
  check();
}
//... continue on with Jason's functions
```

Or, since you've set them up in an array, you could also just use the buttons' indices as your check sequence.  Something like:

```
function redYellowBlue(e:MouseEvent){
  checkString += String(buttons.indexOf(e.currentTarget));
  check();
}

function check(){
  if (checkString == '201') {
    // ... handle correct sequence
  }
}
```

Also, just a best practice tip:

only use a leading capital for names of classes.  Instance names and function names should start with a lowercase.  (leading cap won't break anything, but it's standard practice)

Answer (score 0):

//Here is code

```
var buttons:Array = new Array(YellowButton, BlueButton, RedButton);



for(var i:int=0;i< buttons.length;i++) 
{
  buttons[a].buttonMode=true 
  buttons[a].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,buttonsClickHandler); 
} 

function buttonsClickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void { 

    var button:MovieClip = MovieClip(event.target);

    switch(button.name)
    {
        case "YellowButton":
        case "BlueButton":
        gotoAndStop(2);
        break;
        case "RedButton":
        gotoAndStop(3);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Strah has been very helpful